# Error when I press C to reload/re-execute code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to make a snake game using TheNewBoston's tutorials, since I am a Middle School student and dont have much experience in python. The code is:

```
__author__ = 'Ded'

import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

pygame.display.set_caption('Dipshit')

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

block_size = 10
FPS = 30

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)

def message_to_screen(msg,color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])


def gameLoop():
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    lead_x = display_width/2
    lead_y = display_height/2
    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0

    while not gameExit:

        while gameOver == True:
            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            message_to_screen("Game over, press C to play again or Q to quit", red)
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameExit = True
                        gameOver = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    lead_x_change -= block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    lead_x_change += block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    lead_y_change += block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    lead_y_change -= block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change = 0

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lead_y_change = 0

        if lead_x >= display_width or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= display_height or lead_y < 0:
            gameOver = True

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x,lead_y,block_size,block_size])


        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

gameLoop()
```

However, I get this error when I execute, play, lose and press C to retry. Q works fine when I want to quit but C just quits, and prints this error:

> C:\Python34\python.exe "C:/Users/Ded/PycharmProjects/PyGame/PyGame
>   Tutorial.py" Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Ded/PycharmProjects/PyGame/PyGame Tutorial.py", line 100, in
>   
>       gameLoop()   File "C:/Users/Ded/PycharmProjects/PyGame/PyGame Tutorial.py", line 56, in gameLoop
>       gameLoop()   File "C:/Users/Ded/PycharmProjects/PyGame/PyGame Tutorial.py", line 76, in gameLoop
>       if event.type == pygame.KEYUP: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'event' referenced before assignment
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I think you want to indent your two `if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:` blocks in the `for even in pygame.event.get()` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indent these parts of the code:

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            lead_x_change = 0

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            lead_y_change = 0
```

so that they are part of the `for` loop. Otherwise if there are no events to get and no iterations of the loop occur, the variable `event` won't be defined.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, sorry that I didn't see it before. It works like a charm now.